# Crystal Reports Arabic Characters Issue

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, arabic

I have purchased Crystal Reports 2013 with Arabic enabled. The problem is that fields from the database which contain Arabic characters are not being displayed properly. They are merely showing as '?????' characters instead.

I have tried changing the font but with no success. I have Win 8.1 Pro and SQL Server 2012.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: create a text field in your Crystal Report (a label). Place Arabic characters into that field (just by typing them into it on the report definition). Run the report. If they display correctly then its probably not Crystal, but rather would point to an issue in the data retrieval and supply to Crystal via your dataset (or whatever datasource you are using). If they don't display - then its definitely Crystal. I know this doesn't solve your problem, but its the first step.

Comment: @robnick
I can type arabic text just fine. Some attributes(fields) display arabic normally. The majority across the database are displaying junk data. Even when i browse field data they show as junk

Comment: Okay so the thing is you need to eliminate what is *not* the problem (think of Sherlock Holmes) - whatever is left *is* the problem. If Crystal Reports (not browsing the DB, not looking at code, not typing stuff into notepad etc.) can display Arabic in a simple field - then its probably not Crystal Reports. Some things to try: (a) When you extra the data from the DB, is the data in a nvarchar() field... I'm pretty sure Arabic will be double byte encoded, (b) can you try and hard code Arabic text into your datasource and verify it displays etc. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How-to-Export-Crystal-Report-in-Regional-Language](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/749570/How-to-Export-Crystal-Report-in-Regional-Language)

Here is good example how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i solved the problem.
Eventhough I have Arabic enabled on my win 8.1 pro, it seems that CR isn't recognizing arabic Unicode characters. I simply changed windows locale to Arabic and it works like a charm.
Thanks for all who helped troubleshoot this problem, sherlock holmes style. :)